# PDFMiner Version diffs？Getting UnsupportedOperation: seek

Tags: python, pdfminer, unsupportedoperation

I'm using crawlers to get some pdf files from website and tring to converted into txt and I get this Error Getting UnsupportedOperation: seek.

I have searched lots of website and just cannot help me solve the problem.

File "", line 51, in parse
praser_pdf = PDFParser(fp)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfparser.py", line 43, in **init**
PSStackParser.**init**(self, fp)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\psparser.py", line 515, in **init**
PSBaseParser.**init**(self, fp)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\psparser.py", line 169, in **init**
self.seek(0)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\psparser.py", line 527, in seek
PSBaseParser.seek(self, pos)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\psparser.py", line 199, in seek
self.fp.seek(pos)

UnsupportedOperation: seek

And Here is my code

```
baseurl = "http://reportdocs.static.szse.cn/UpFiles/fxklwxhj/"

def parse(docucode):

_path = baseurl + quote(docucode) +"?random=0.3006649122149502"

request = Request(url=_path, headers=headers)  

fp = urlopen(request)

praser_pdf = PDFParser(fp)

doc = PDFDocument()

praser_pdf.set_document(doc)
doc.set_parser(praser_pdf)

doc.initialize()
```

The code can not work and it just break down in praser_pdf = PDFParser(fp), and I really want to know how to fix it!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you provide the version of pdfminer you are using

Comment: the version of pdfminer is 20191125 ( the latest version). Thanks!

Comment: command = "pdf2txt.py -t html -o {} {} ".format(output_file, input_file)
os.system(command)
you an use like this like save the output from fp to a file, load it as input_file and the output will be saved in output_file. Make sure to add the python scripts folder to your path or use the absolute path of the pdf2txt.py if required

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/ for reference

Comment: could you please explain more about how to save the output from fp to a file and load it as input_file?  Especially thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample implementation of reading the pdf from a url and writing to a output file.
Note: This implementation works for pdfminer:20191125 and haven't included error handling for the response from the url

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import os
pdf_url = "http://www.inkwelleditorial.com/pdfSample.pdf"
rp1 = Request(pdf_url)
fp = urlopen(rp1)
output_path = "/home/mint/Desktop/temper.html"
input_path = "/home/mint/Desktop/temper.pdf"

open(input_path, "w").close() # For making the output file as empty before going forward
with open(input_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(fp.read())
command = "pdf2txt.py -t html -o {} {} ".format(output_path, input_path)
os.system(command)
```